# Reload static fields in a java class

Tags: java, static

I have a class in java which has a number of static final strings and one static Locale variable.

These Strings are basically keys to a messagebundle which return the translated Strings using the locale.

i.e.,

```
public static Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
public static String MSG1 = Translator.get(locale, "MSG1");
//Similar Strings.
```

This locale variable is set at runtime based on the browser locale. 
But since these are static variables, they are already initialized with the default locale and changes to the `locale` variable does not have any effect.

Is there a way to "reload" these strings everytime the `locale`variable is changed?

I don't want to make the obvious change(making all the strings non static and initializing locale in constructor/method) because this class has a lot of messages(250+) and is used in too many places.

Comment: `private static void onLocaleChanged(Locale locale) {
// change fields
}`

Comment: Don't use the intermediate `MSG1` strings and just call `Translator.get(locale, "MSG1");` in your code.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: That's slow, would involve a lot of copy&paste and doesn't really solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. While you can't get Java to run the assignments again, you can move the assignments into a method instead:

```
public static String MSG1;

public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
   MSG1 = Translator.get(locale, "MSG1");
}

static {
    setLocale( Locale.getDefault() );
}
```

After that, you can use the method `setLocale()` to switch the locale. When the class is loaded for the first time, the locale is set using the static initializer block at the end.

**[EDIT]** This of course doesn't work in a multi-threaded environment: Static variables are global (= shared between all threads). What's worse: Due to Java's memory model, a change of the variable in thread 1 might not be visible at any specific point in time to any other threads.

If you need this in a web server, then you can't use static variables anymore. I suggest to create an instance of the class and convert all the static fields into methods. Then you can create this instance in a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and put it in the request and configure it correctly.

```
public class I18nHelper {
    public static I18nHelper get( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        return (HttpServletRequest) request.getAttribute( "I18nHelper" );
    }

    private Locale locale;

    public I18nHelper(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String msg1() {
        return Translator.get(locale, "MSG1");
    }
}
```

This approach has another huge advantage: You can pass type-safe arguments!

```
    public String fileNotFoundMsg( File file ) {
        ... format message with parameter "file" and return it...
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to implement this approach, but one more doubt: Since the setLocale(locale) can be called from different browsers which might be in different locales _at the same time_, wouldn't that cause a problem?

Can the static messages model be maintained at all in that case?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a local reference in every place that uses this variable, just use the static method itself.

Meaning, if you have a method:

```
public void doSomething() {
   if(locale.isSomeLocale()) { // Do something }
}
```

Just do:

```
public void doSomething() {
   if(Locale.getDefault().isSomeLocale()) { // Do something }
}
```

I think that's the cleanest option you can have. If you try to update 200+ local variables, every time the static variable changes, you'll have a terrible mess. This way, every point in your code is aligned with the locale you use.

Answer (score 2):

> But since these are static variables, they are already initialized
>   with the default locale and changes to the locale variable does not
>   have any effect.

You can reassign a static variable, unless, it's final.